# How to Remove Compatibility Mode settings from the registry -visual studio2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

i was try to set always run as administrator,so, then I was troubleshoot the visualstudio 2017.  after open the visual studio it's throw multiple error there are before it was working fine.

[image]

after continue the

[image]

VS 2017 was running windows 8 compatibility mode.not open any file

i was check the unrecognized guid format.it's based on compatibility mode in registry. but, I don't know how to change the compatibility mode in registry or any place in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Under this registry key, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers, delete the entry for Visual Studio.